# How Can I Handle Single and Double Click Events On a Listbox WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I'm trying to handle single and double click events on the listbox items. I've used `MouseDoubleClick` (to listen double click) and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` (to listen single click). Now when I run the application, the double click event wouldn't trigger because every time `MouseDoubleClick` gets trigger. Here's my xaml code, I would like to know what event I should use to handle both, appreciate any help. Thank you.

**Edit**: My code is not able to trigger double click because it trigger single clicked event 2x times.

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Name="detailList" 
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         MouseDoubleClick="detailList_MouseDoubleClick"
         PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="DetailList_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
         >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="90" >
                <Image Width="80" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                <TextBlock  Width="60" Height="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="11" Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks Hille, but suggested duplicated question didn't cover the whole problem. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second click of a double-click is by definition *always* preceded by a single click.

You could use a timer to wait for like 200 ms to see if there is another click following the first one.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer _timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2); //wait for the other click for 200ms
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
    }

    private void lv_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("double click"); //handle the double click event here...
        }
        else
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("click"); //handle the Click event here...
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

---

```
<ListBox PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="lv_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ... />
```

Comment: Hi mm8, Thank you for your answer. I think we don't have such event available to differentiate between two events. In that case, I'll accept your answer. Its old school but it will work. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

I cant find a good solution, but you can go around the problem with counting the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` in a period of time.

```
If the mouse was clicked only one time in 0.3 sec, do ...

If the mouse was clicket two times in 0.3 sec, do ...
```

Comment: Hi Hille. Thanks for your suggestion. I had this idea on my mind too. this would let dig into old style code so, I'm looking for available updated solution to handle these events.

Comment: Take a look at the possible duplicate i marked, may it can help you out :)

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate suggestion, but that do not cover the whole problem. In that post, they discussed double click but didn't cover how they'd differentiate between single and double clicks.

Comment: I cant find something on the inet too. So if you find a solution let us know

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll let you know if I find the solution. Cheers :-)